# How to report the unweighted number of missing values when using gtsummary :: tbl_svy_summary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

We analyze weighted survey data and we want to report the unweighted frequencies for categorical variables (in addition to the weighted %). But the {n_unweighted} option in the statistic argument does not work for missing values.

Please find below the problem shown when applying code to hdv2003 data from package question r

```
library(questionr)
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)

data(hdv2003)
dp <- svydesign(ids=~1, weight= ~poids, data=hdv2003)
dp %>%
tbl_svysummary(
include=c("sexe", "nivetud"),
by="sexe",
statistic=all_categorical()~"{n_unweighted} ({p}%)",
missing = "ifany"
)
```

[table of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCDIe.jpg)

Comment: Can you please update your post to include reproducible code (i.e. code we can all run on our machines)? Also, which unweighted statistic are you referring to exactly? There are three referenced in your example. To that end, please make your example minimal, meaning it only includes the bare minimum to illustrate the issue you're having.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my post by applying code to hdv2003 data included in the package questionr

Answer (score 1):

The unknown row N cannot be modified via the statistics argument (well, cannot be modified at all, just reports the weighted N!). You can, however, add the unweighted missing N via the `add_n()` function. Example below!

```r
library(questionr)
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)

data(hdv2003)
dp <- svydesign(ids=~1, weight= ~poids, data=hdv2003)
tbl <-
  dp %>%
  tbl_svysummary(
    include=c("sexe", "nivetud"),
    by="sexe",
    statistic=all_categorical()~"{n_unweighted} ({p}%)",
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_n("{N_miss_unweighted}") %>%
  modify_header(n ~ "**Unweighted N Missing**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response ! We will add the column with the unweighted missing N